# How to automatically link data in a sheet to other one? (Google sheet)

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm making a class attendance by using Google form:

- **Picture 1**: This is a reponse of the form
  [image]
- **Picture 2**: Here's my question: How to aumatically link data "Present", "Absence" in "Form Responsse" to cells D4, D5, D6 in "Sheet1" that depends on date and name. 
  [image]

Please help me! Any method such as function, google script. Thank you.

Comment: Hey @Khoa Anh - welcome to SO! :) Could you please insert the image into the question please? It helps us help you & good luck.

Comment: It doesn't allow me to insert directly :( it said that I have to earn 10 reputations in order that it can allow me to insert directly :( please click 2 links of pictures.

Comment: Thank you @|'-'| for that :)

Comment: This is not as simple as it looks. First, on Form Response sheet, the name of student is hidden behind "Class Attendance [". Of course there is a way to get the name out of that format using `=MID()`, it will fail when you want to change the format, like into "Student name : ___" or something - which, in consequence, will make the rest of your formula fail. The same apply to your timestamp: At least make the timestamp in the two sheet identical with each other, especially when you need to compare data. After you have the name and timestamp right, the answer might even pop before you know it.

Comment: Thank you @HaPhan. I added a new column "timestamp" on sheet 2. At the end of your comment, how to identify 2 timestamp Ha?

Comment: What I mean is, can you provide any formula to compare if the date in sheet1 is the same as sheet2 or not ? Usually, you will be able to compare two date using a simple `=` operator.

Comment: Ahhh. I understand. Please keep in touch.